# asp.net mvc bind a specific model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have a model with a collection

```
public class Model
{
     IEnumerable<ModelPart> Parts {get;set;}
}

public class Parts 
{
     public string Prop1 {get;set;}
     public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

But the comming in url is quite nasty.

It has this form

dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_1_0=&dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_1_1=sssss&dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_1_2=ssssss&
dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_2_0=&dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_2_1=aaaa&dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_2_2=aaaaa

It has three parts separated with underscore

dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_2_1

1. Some id `dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc`
2. Row id `2`
3. Cell id `1`

I'm wondering what would be the best way bind this to my model.

I was thinking of renaming this `dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc_2_1` to `model[2].Prop1` Where would be the best place to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yeah, that's a hell of an ugly request string. A custom model binder is the way to parse this beast until you find a real solution to this problem which of course is fixing the system sending this crap to conform to the default model binder syntax.

And here's an example of some scratch code that might put you on the right track:

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private const string Prefix = "dhxGridObj_d3BIc6JfDidc";

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as Model;
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        model.Parts = request
            .Params
            .Keys
            .OfType<string>()
            .Select(key => Regex.Match(key, Prefix + "_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)"))
            .Where(x => x.Success)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Row = x.Groups[1].Value,
                Col = x.Groups[2].Value
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Row)
            .Select(x => new Parts
            {
                Prop1 = request[string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", Prefix, x.Key, x.ElementAt(0).Col)],
                Prop2 = request[string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", Prefix, x.Key, x.ElementAt(1).Col)],
            });
        return model;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Model), new MyModelBinder());
```

Comment: Forgot to mention there is also some validation going on on the Parts class. I've had a look at the defaultmodelbinder class.There're couple of methods to override. Could you give a hint which one would be the best for this ?

Comment: @user256034, you derive from `DefaultModelBinder` and override the `BindModel` method where you perform the logic of parsing those ugly query string parameters and binding them to their corresponding property values.

Comment: Wow this awesome. Works like a charm. But I guess I have to do the validation by myself, don't I ?

Comment: @user256034, what kind of validation do you need? You could decorate your model properties with the necessary attributes.

Comment: Yes , I meaned DataAnnotations. I have on some properties of the Parts class some attributes. But I don't see the place where the validation should happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use query string parameters in url of your MVC application. the best for this is Url routes. you can find a good article for routes in MVC here :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: but this is big hole in MVC Application.